# Get the nth item of a generator in Python

Tags: python, generator

Is there a more syntactically concise way of writing the following?

```
gen = (i for i in xrange(10))
index = 5
for i, v in enumerate(gen):
    if i is index:
        return v
```

It seems almost natural that a generator should have a `gen[index]` expression, that acts as a list, but is functionally identical to the above code.

Comment: You don't want `is` in this situation (or many situations at all). `is` is for comparing identity, not equality. You want `==`. This will probably work in this instance, but only by coincidence and implementation detail.

Comment: Since I'm using integers, how could it not work? Is it even good practice to expect the `index` object to implement `__eq__` in cases such as this? (This is getting off topic...)

Comment: Try `1000 is 500 + 500`, it will (probably) be `False`. See, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/python-is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers

Comment: +1 for this question. It does seem strange that there's not a less verbose way to say "the nth result of gen".

Comment: Another possibility is zippers --- they handle arbitrary trees, but a list is a tree too. See this implementation https://github.com/trivio/zipper/blob/master/tests/test_zipper.py

Comment: Use `is` for `is True` or `is None`. For `int` using `==` is fine, but not for `float` where you should compare a difference to a tolerance like `< 1e-7`.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

one method would be to use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)

```
>>> gen = (x for x in range(10))
>>> index = 5
>>> next(itertools.islice(gen, index, None))
5
```

Answer (score 19):

I think the best way is :

```py
next(x for i,x in enumerate(it) if i==n)
```

(where `it` is your iterator and `n` is the index)

It doesn't require you to add an import (like the solutions using `itertools`) nor to load all the elements of the iterator in memory at once (like the solutions using `list`).

Note 1: this version throws a `StopIteration` error if your iterator has less than n items. If you want to get `None` instead, you can use :

```py
next((x for i,x in enumerate(it) if i==n), None)
```

Note 2: There are no brackets inside the call to `next`. This is not a list comprehension, but a generator comprehension, that does not consume the original iterator further than its nth element.

Answer (score 17):

You could do this, using `count` as an example generator:

```
from itertools import islice, count
next(islice(count(), n, n+1))
```

Comment: What version of Python is this? The above code gives me the error `AttributeError: 'itertools.islice' object has no attribute 'next'` in 3.3.

Comment: In Python 3x, change `next` to `__next__()`, i.e., `islice(count, n, n=1).__next__()`

Comment: So it's better to use `next(islice(count(), n, n+1))`.

Comment: I think you can get rid of the upper bound, i.e. `next(islice(count(), n, None))`.

Answer (score 12):

I'd argue against the temptation to treat generators like lists. The simple but naive approach is the simple one-liner:

```
gen = (i for i in range(10))
list(gen)[3]
```

But remember, generators aren't like lists. They don't store their intermediate results anywhere, so you can't go backwards. I'll demonstrate the problem with a simple example in the python repl:

```
>>> gen = (i for i in range(10))
>>> list(gen)[3]
3
>>> list(gen)[3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Once you start going through a generator to get the nth value in the sequence, the generator is now in a different state, and attempting to get the nth value again will return you a different result, which is likely to result in a bug in your code.

Let's take a look at another example, based on the code from the question.

One would initially expect the following to print `4` twice.

```
gen = (i for i in range(10))
index = 4
for i, v in enumerate(gen):
    if i == index:
        answer = v
        break
print(answer)
for i, v in enumerate(gen):
    if i == index:
        answer = v
        break
print(answer)
```

but type this into the repl and you get:

```
>>> gen = (i for i in range(10))
>>> index = 4
>>> for i, v in enumerate(gen):
...     if i == index:
...             answer = v
...             break
... 
>>> print(answer)
4
>>> for i, v in enumerate(gen):
...     if i == index:
...             answer = v
...             break
... 
>>> print(answer)
9
```

Good luck tracing that bug down.

---

As pointed out, if the generator is infinitely long, you can't even convert it to a list. The expression `list(gen)` will never finish.

There is a way you could put a lazily evaluated caching wrapper around an infinite generator to make it look like an infinitely long list you could index into at will, but that deserves its own question and answer, and would have major performance implications.

Comment: What if the generator is infinite?

Comment: This should be higher up, as doing this comes at a significant cost in terms of time. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3):

If `n` is known at authoring-time, you can use destructuring. e.g. to get the 3rd item:

```
>>> _, _, third, *rest = range(10)
>>> third
2
>>> rest
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution would be:

```
[_ for _ in range(n-1) if next(gen) and False ]
return next(gen)
```

As `next(gen) and False` is always false, the list comprehension does nothing but executing `next(gen)` n-1 times.

In my testing, it is as fast as using `itertools.islice`

Comment: I like it a lot, this doesn't import `itertools` or pretends to create a "slice", instead simply "jumps" through the iterator and returns the `next()` value.

Comment: Check out [my take on this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73425727/9288580), with some criticisms =)

Comment: @KlasŠ. you misread my solution. As "next(gen) and False" is always false, it never adds anything to the list. It only creates an empty list, make some kind of empty loop then discard the still empty list. It means to be memory efficient.

Comment: Right you are, totally missed that, my bad =)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that came to my mind was:

```
gen = (i for i in xrange(10))
index = 5

for i, v in zip(range(index), gen): pass

return v
```

Answer (score 0):

Building up on [*@Madlozoz* answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72817329/9288580), but with mighty [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions):

```
>>> gen = (x ** 2 for x in itertools.count())
>>> [v := next(gen) for _ in range(10)]
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
>>> v
81
```

The thing I don't like about this (*unlike Madlozoz'*) solution is that potentially huge list is constructed just to be discarded immediately.

---

A simple `for` loop is another way:

```
# `gen` continues from the previous snippet
>>> for _ in range(3):
...     v = next(gen)
...
>>> print(v)
144
```

At a cost of extra line we can save some process ticks on assignments as well and spend them on wrapper class:

```
class IterIndexer:

    def __init__(self, iter_):
        self.iter = iter_

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        for _ in range(i - 1):
            next(self.iter)
        return next(self.iter)


gen = (x ** 2 for x in itertools.count())
gen = IterIndexer(gen)
print(gen[14])
```

```
169
```

It'd be even cooler to wrap it properly, so that you can use wrapper instance for everything instead of original generator or iterator, but that's another question =)

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps you should elaborate more on a actual use case.

```
>>> gen = xrange(10)
>>> ind=5 
>>> gen[ind]
5
```

Comment: I editted `xrange(10)` to `(i for i in xrange(10))`. Turns out this syntax works for `xrange` since it's not really a generator...

Comment: `xrange` predates generators, and returns an xrange object, which actually implements the full sequence protocol.

Answer (score -2):

**Best to use is :** 
example :

```
a = gen values ('a','c','d','e')
```

so the answer will be :

```
a = list(a) -> this will convert the generator to a list (it will store in memory)
```

then when you want to go specific index you will :

```
a[INDEX] -> and you will able to get the value its holds
```

if you want to know only the count or to do operations that not required store in memory best practice will be :
`a = sum(1 in i in a)` -> this will count the number of objects you have

hope i made it more simple.