# How to scrape text with no specific class

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

How do I scrape text with no specific class? I have pulled up a past eBay listing that sold via auction. Here is the snippet of code from the heading section.

```
<h1 class="it-ttl" id="itemTitle" itemprop="name"><span class="g-hdn">Details about   </span>2018 Panini Contenders Josh Allen #105 No Feet RC Ticket Auto PSA 10 GEM
```

I want to be able to scrape just the text ***"2018 Panini Contenders Josh Allen #105 No Feet RC Ticket Auto PSA 10 GEM"*** with requests and beautiful soup, but there is no class assigned to that specific text.

Here is the code I have so far...

[my work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6nwP.png)

Currently working on this line.

```
h1 = soup.find('h1', id="itemTitle")
    print(h1)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If it is simply the text you can use `h1.text`

Comment: @Thymen that will include `Details about` in the output, which the OP doesn't want

Comment: Right, which you could of course filter afterwards (python 3.9 `removeprefix`), but the answer from [Mendelg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65063307/10961342) is then neater.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `find_next()` method with `text=True`, which will return the first text  match, and than use `.next` to get the next text after that. For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = '''
<h1 class="it-ttl" id="itemTitle" itemprop="name"><span class="g-hdn">Details about   </span>2018 Panini Contenders Josh Allen #105 No Feet RC Ticket Auto PSA 10 GEM
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

print(soup.find(id='itemTitle').find_next(text=True).next)
```

Output:

```
2018 Panini Contenders Josh Allen #105 No Feet RC Ticket Auto PSA 10 GEM
```

Answer (score 0):

You could index into a list comprehension based on stripped_strings generator, or itertools.islice into the generator. The latter I found out was possible from [@cobbal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2300766/6241235)

---

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<h1 class="it-ttl" id="itemTitle" itemprop="name"><span class="g-hdn">Details about   </span>2018 Panini Contenders Josh Allen #105 No Feet RC Ticket Auto PSA 10 GEM
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

print([s for s in soup.select_one('#itemTitle').stripped_strings][1])


from itertools import islice

next(islice(soup.select_one('#itemTitle').stripped_strings, 1, None))
```