# Iterating or accessing a python generator with index

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

Is it possible to iterate over a python `generator` with `index` like a `list` or access a `generator` element through `index`

For example:

```
sample_list = [1,2,3,4]
for i in range(len(sample_list)): #iterating with index
   print (sample_list[i]) #accessing element through index
```

Comment: Related: [Get the nth item of a generator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300756/get-the-nth-item-of-a-generator-in-python)

Comment: @Brian Thanks for the response. Its more of accessing it with a given index, I am looking to iterate through it with ```index```. I will check if I can use that.

Comment: Could you comment why you want to index a generator? Do you want to have access to an index while you're consuming it? Or do you want to skip the first n-1 yielded values to immediately get the nth? Or something else?

Comment: @Brian check for a ```value``` at index ```i``` if it certifies a ```condition``` I want to access ```i+1``` or skip ```i+1``` and go to ```i+2```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you familiar with the `enumerate` function?

```
for i, value in enumerate(your_gen):
    print(i)
    print(value)
```