# Read only a specific line from a json file

Tags: python, json, file

I have a large json file containing +8 million lines. Due to memory restriction i'm trying to find how to only read a specific line from the file without load the whole file into memory.

What i'm looking for is function that basically behaves like this:

```
def read_line(file_name, line_number)
 return the line line_number from the file file_name
```

Comment: Maybe something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54333239/147356), taking advantage of the fact that an open file is a line iterator?

Comment: Is it static data? If yes, then if you can get the position instead of line number you can use fseek to jump to that position. If it's not static, then line number probably won't work anyway?

Comment: Read the file line-by-line, keeping track of the line number you're currently on, and stop when you reach the desired line number.  What is the difficulty?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about cache, you can loop on the file using a context manager.

```py
def read_line(file_path: str, line_num: int) -> str:
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        for number, line in enumerate(file):
            if number == line_num:
                return line
```

Comment: Note the file object is iterable weither you use a context manager or not.

Comment: @bfontaine Yes indeed. The advantage of using the context manager is that the file will be closed automatically and, as resources are relevant, this is important to me.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what you are looking for-

```
import linecache

def read_line(file_name, line_number):
    return linecache.getline(file_name, line_number)

line_number = 2
file_name = 'sample-json-file.json'
line = read_line(file_name, line_number)
print(line)
```

Comment: The documentation for `linecache` says it is intended to "Cache lines from Python source files."  Does it work with plain text files also?

Comment: Are you sure this is efficient? The [source code for `linecache`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/552b2646b75d079e9b31d4e800fbb2234624ed44/Lib/linecache.py#L30-L32) seems to use an array of all lines.

Comment: I did a few tests and it turns out that this solution is terribly inefficient, both in term of time and memory usage. To get the second line of my test file with 16M lines, @LorenzoP’s simple answer runs instantaneously (0.05s) with a negligible RAM usage, while the code in this answer takes 7.6s (!!) because it loads all the file in RAM (!!!).